# Exiting TOAD while cancel pending?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Quick question: Does exiting out of TOAD (for Oracle) while it is trying to cancel a pending query harmful?

Should I be letting this dialog box run its course?

I did have the screenshot but am unable to post pics until I have 10 reps.

EDIT: It has been going for around 30 minutes now.
EDIT2: I should mention it is not an update query, purely search.

Thanks,

Comment: Not harmful, but for excessive CPU usage, in case of a costly query. You can ask ur DBA to kill it anyways

Comment: Not a real answer, hence the use of comments, but you can use ALT+F4 to close this dialog and regain use of your TOAD window without closing TOAD. Whether you SHOULD or not is another matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this happens and I've already waited long enough (and the **`Cancel`** button has no effect), I open *Task Manager* and apply *"End Process Tree"* command on the `Toad.exe` process.

If a database connection is lost, all uncommitted changes made are automatically rolled back by the database. **So it is not harmful.**

Once I investigated this by looking up the sessions list. It looks like this happens when Toad somehow loses the connection to the server in the midst of executing a query.

When you wonder why the query is taking so long (when it shouldn't) and click the **`Cancel`** button, Toad enters a state of *"limbo"* where it's waiting for the result of the *cancel* operation from the server (not aware of connection loss).

The problem is that there is no way to stop this *waiting* and go back to normal. This is a bug in Toad. There is no other way around this. I am not sure when they will fix it, if at all.

Comment: Thanks for that. I always wondered exactly why it took forever. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my query!

Answer (score 2):

I just had same problem.

[LIKE THIS FOR DAYS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z08s.png)

One solution to cancel the running process (processing or canceling) in TOAD which take time (keep processing for longer hours and same going for hours) is

JUST disable the internet connection which auto cancels the toad process.

Later go to Session > Test connection to reconnect to servers

Comment: Thanks, disabling the network connection does help to stop TOAD from the infinite loop of `Cancel pending please wait`

Comment: "JUST disable the internet connection which auto cancels the toad process", That fixed the problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These steps helped me at least:

1. Session -> TestConnection (Reconnect)

   This step will take some time, have patience (You may get TOAD: Not Responding)
2. Debug -> Halt Execution

At least You do not have to forcibly kill the process from TASK MANAGER.

Keep querying :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the sys / dba level access to the target database then go and kill the toad session, I wrote the following query to identify and kill my toad session which was running for 30 mins and wasting my precious time.

SQL> select sid, username, serial#, status from v$session where machine like '%ACC%';

```
   SID USERNAME                          SERIAL# STATUS
```

---

```
   989 SYS                                  1307 INACTIVE
   991 PIN                                 15780 ACTIVE
```

SQL> alter system kill session '991,15780' immediate;
ORA-00031: session marked for kill

And boom !! Toad returned the session and control :)

Regards,
Sayeed Shaikh